# i've a problem with my form that i tried validating it with php then it should send the data to the firebase

Tags: php, html, forms, firebase

it always gives me the first condition which gives me "Name Cannot be empty." and it dosen't send the data...

i tried changing the $_POST['inputs']  with variables but everytime it gives me undefined index

inside the script there's the code that sends the data to firebase

what seems to be the problem here

```
    
                                    <form class="pb-5 ml-5" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="inputName" name="inputName">
                                                    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left">الإسم</label>
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control text-right" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail">
                                              <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left" >الإيميل</label>
                                                            <input type="password" class="form-control text-right" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword">
                                                    <label for="staticPassword" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left">كلمة المرور</label>
                                                        <input type="tel" id="inputNum" class="form-control text-right" name="inputNum">
                                                    <label for="staticNum" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left" >رقم الموبايل</label>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1" />
                                                    <input type="button" value="اشترك" class="btn btn-danger w-50 mr-5" id="create-newuser-button" name="createUser">
                                    </form>
                            </section>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $nameEmptyErr = $emailEmptyErr = $mobNumEmptyErr = $passwordEmptyErr = "";
                    $nameErr = $emailErr = $mobNumErr = $passwordErr = "";
                    $validation = true;
    
                    //Name Validation
                    if (empty($_POST['inputName'])) {
                        $nameEmptyErr = '<div class="error">
                                                    Name cannot be empty.
                                                </div>';
                        echo $nameEmptyErr;
                    } else {
                        $name = test_input($_POST['inputName']);
    
    
                        //Email Validation
                        if (empty($_POST['inputEmail'])) {
                            $emailEmptyErr = '<div class="error">
                                                        Email cannot be empty.
                                                    </div>';
                            echo $emailEmptyErr;
                        } else {
                            $email = test_input($_POST['inputEmail']);
    
                            //Password Validation
                            if (empty($_POST['inputPassword'])) {
                                $passwordEmptyErr = '<div class="error">
                                                        Password cannot be empty.
                                                    </div>';
                                echo $passwordEmptyErr;
                            } else {
                                $password = test_input($_POST['inputPassword']);
    
                                //Mobile Number Validation
                                if (empty($_POST['inputNum'])) {
                                    $mobNumEmptyErr = '<div class="error">
                                                        Mobile Number cannot be empty.
                                                    </div>';
                                    echo $mobNumEmptyErr;
                                } else {
                                    $mobNum = test_input($_POST['inputNum']);
                                    $validation = true;
    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
    
                    function test_input($data)
                    {
                        $data = trim($data);
                        $data = stripslashes($data);
                        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    
                        return $data;
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST['createUser']) && $validation = true) :
                    ?>
                    <script type='text/javascript'></script>
                    <?php
                        endif;
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page isn't testing to see if it has been submitted. As a result it displays your form and immediately starts validating the parameters - which aren't yet there.

You also don't seem to have a `submit` button, so there's no way to submit the form. If you have such a button you can test for it and do the validation if you find it.

Rework your page like this:

```
// Add a test for the presence of the submit button. 
//If not found, display a form, otherwise do the validation
if (!isset($_POST['createUser'])) {
?>
<div>
<section>

    <!-- No need to specify an action if the form is submitting to the same page. -->
    <form class="pb-5 ml-5"  method="POST">

        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="inputName" name="inputName">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left">الإسم</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control text-right" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left" >الإيميل</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control text-right" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword">
        <label for="staticPassword" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left">كلمة المرور</label>
        <input type="tel" id="inputNum" class="form-control text-right" name="inputNum">
        <label for="staticNum" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left" >رقم الموبايل</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1" />

        <!-- Change this element to type="submit" -->
        <input type="submit" value="اشترك" class="btn btn-danger w-50 mr-5" id="create-newuser-button" name="createUser">
    </form>
</section>
</div>
<?php
} else {
    // Do your validation here
}
```

Comment: but actually there's another problem that the page redirects to a blank page before sending the data to the database and it's recognized as "undefined"